# Capturing consecutive non-alphanumeric characters in a string in a single group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all special characters in a string with dashes.  I use the following regex to replace the characters.

```
var x = "Querty(&)keypad";
alert(x.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, "-"));
```

However, this causes each character to be replaced by a dash, rather than replacing consecutive characters with a single dash. This examples gives me the output `Querty---keypad`. My desired output is `Querty-keypad`.

You can see the issue in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkBfU/99/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `+` to match 1 or more repetitions:

```
> "Querty(&)keypad".replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, "-")
"Querty-keypad"
```